# Jitsi_meet_wrapper: Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network. Retrying Gradle Build: #3, wait time: 400ms

Tags: flutter, zoom-sdk, jitsi-meet

I'm working on zoom clone app in flutter.
I'm using jitsi_meeet_wrapper plugin for implementing zoom functionalities.

Even after following each and every step shown in documentation getting below error.

> BUILD FAILED in 2m 22s
> [!] Gradle threw an error while downloading artifacts from the network.
> Retrying Gradle Build: #3, wait time: 400ms

Full Error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:8.1.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :jitsi_meet_wrapper
      > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:8.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/8.1.2/jitsi-meet-sdk-8.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/8.1.2/jitsi-meet-sdk-8.1.2.pom'.
               > Connect to raw.githubusercontent.com:443 [raw.githubusercontent.com/49.44.79.236, raw.githubusercontent.com/2405:200:1607:2820:41:0:0:36] failed: Connection timed out: no further information
      > Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:8.1.2.
         > Could not get resource 'https://www.jitpack.io/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/8.1.2/jitsi-meet-sdk-8.1.2.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://www.jitpack.io/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/8.1.2/jitsi-meet-sdk-8.1.2.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I tried cleaning cache, and rebuilding app. But nothing is working for me.